# how to insert a line text after specific number of lines

Tags: powershell

I have already reading line by line.

```
foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("C:\temp\test.txt"))
{
    $line
}
```

Results:

> (1, 1, 1, 42.48333330, 1.46666670, N'Aixàs'), 
> (2, 1, 1, 42.46666670, 1.50000000, N'Aixirivali'), 
> (3, 1, 1, 42.46666670, 1.50000000, N'Aixirivall'), 
> (4, 1, 1, 42.46666670, 1.50000000, N'Aixirvall'), 
> (5, 1, 1, 42.46666670, 1.48333330, N'Aixovall'), 
> (6, 2, 1, 42.50000000, 1.51666670, N'Andorra'), 
> (7, 2, 1, 42.50000000, 1.51666670, N'Andorra la Vella'), 
> (8, 2, 1, 42.50000000, 1.51666670, N'Andorra-Vieille'), 
> (9, 2, 1, 42.50000000, 1.51666670, N'Andorre'), 
> (10, 2, 1, 42.50000000, 1.51666670, N'Andorre-la-Vieille'),

All what I need to do now is to remove comma on every 900th row and AFTER every 900th row to insert text line("INSERT INTO"). Should be looking like this(example for every 5th row):

> INSERT INTO DBname (id1, id2, id3, long, lat, [name]) VALUES 
> (1, 1, 1, 42.48333330, 1.46666670, N'Aixàs'), 
> (2, 1, 1, 42.46666670, 1.50000000, N'Aixirivali'), 
> (3, 1, 1, 42.46666670, 1.50000000, N'Aixirivall'), 
> (4, 1, 1, 42.46666670, 1.50000000, N'Aixirvall'), 
> (5, 1, 1, 42.46666670, 1.48333330, N'Aixovall')
>
> INSERT INTO DBname (id1, id2, id3, long, lat, [name]) VALUES 
> (6, 2, 1, 42.50000000, 1.51666670, N'Andorra'), 
> (7, 2, 1, 42.50000000, 1.51666670, N'Andorra la Vella'), 
> (8, 2, 1, 42.50000000, 1.51666670, N'Andorra-Vieille'), 
> (9, 2, 1, 42.50000000, 1.51666670, N'Andorre'), 
> (10, 2, 1, 42.50000000, 1.51666670, N'Andorre-la-Vieille')
>
> and so on...

Should I introduce another loop in foreach? I hope for your guide to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed hard to explain with words. So I am using code. You can change the offset value to 900 for your requirements.

```
$File = Get-Content .\Test.txt
$length = $File.Count
$offset = 5
$i = $offset
do
{
    $Line = $File[$i-1].Substring(0, $File[$i-1].LastIndexOf(","))
    $InsertLine = "INSERT INTO DBname (id1, id2, id3, long, lat, [name]) VALUES"

$NewData = "$Line

$InsertLine"

    $File[$i-1] = $NewData
    $i = $i+$offset
}
While ($i -le $length)
$File
```

Comment: Yes!! Thank you  lot! You saved my day! It is working but is not replacing in the same file, or maybe to paste results in another file?

Comment: Well, this will only display it. You can save it in the same file or different one.  Use `$File | Out-File .\Test.txt` or `$File | Out-File .\NewTest.txt`

Answer (score 0):

[`File.ReadLines` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) returns **string**:

> **Return Value**
>  Type: [`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<String>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx)
>  All the
>   lines of the file, or the lines that are the result of a query.

**Example**:

```
PS D:\PShell> $x = [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($File)

PS D:\PShell> $x.GetType() | Format-Table -AutoSize

IsPublic IsSerial Name              BaseType                           
-------- -------- ----              --------                           
False    False    ReadLinesIterator System.IO.Iterator`1[System.String]
```

The following code snipped applied to your example should do the job. (Assumed no empty lines and a trailing comma in each line including the last one.)

```
$index = 4            # change to match your demand
$lines = [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("C:\temp\test.txt") -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
$insert = 'INSERT INTO DBname (id1, id2, id3, long, lat, [name]) VALUES '

$insert
for ( $i=0; $i -lt $lines.Count; $i++ ) {
    if ( $i -gt 0 -and ( ( ($i + 1) % $index ) -eq 0 
                       ) -or ( $i -eq $lines.Count - 1 ) ) 
    {
        $lines[$i].Substring(0, $lines[$i].LastIndexOf(","))
        if ( $i -lt $lines.Count - 1 ) {
            $insert
        }
    } else { 
        $lines[$i]
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
INSERT INTO DBname (id1, id2, id3, long, lat, [name]) VALUES 
(1, 1, 1, 42.48333330, 1.46666670, N'Aixàs'), 
(2, 1, 1, 42.46666670, 1.50000000, N'Aixirivali'), 
(3, 1, 1, 42.46666670, 1.50000000, N'Aixirivall'), 
(4, 1, 1, 42.46666670, 1.50000000, N'Aixirvall')
INSERT INTO DBname (id1, id2, id3, long, lat, [name]) VALUES 
(5, 1, 1, 42.46666670, 1.48333330, N'Aixovall'), 
(6, 2, 1, 42.50000000, 1.51666670, N'Andorra'), 
(7, 2, 1, 42.50000000, 1.51666670, N'Andorra la Vella'), 
(8, 2, 1, 42.50000000, 1.51666670, N'Andorra-Vieille')
INSERT INTO DBname (id1, id2, id3, long, lat, [name]) VALUES 
(9, 2, 1, 42.50000000, 1.51666670, N'Andorre'), 
(10, 2, 1, 42.50000000, 1.51666670, N'Andorre-la-Vieille')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like so:

```
$File = (Get-Content -Path $FilePath) -as [System.Collections.ArrayList];
$Offset = 5;
$InsertStatement = 'INSERT INTO DBname (id1, id2, id3, long, lat, [name]) VALUES';

$File.Count..0 | Where-Object {
        ($_ % $Offset) -eq 0
    } | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -gt 0) {
            $File[$_ - 1] = $File[$_ - 1].Trim().TrimEnd(',');
        }
        $File.Insert($_,$InsertStatement);
    }

while (($File[$File.Count - 1] -eq $InsertStatement) -or [System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($File[$File.Count - 1])) {
    $File.Remove($File.Count - 1);
}

File[$File.Count - 1] = $File[$File.Count - 1].Trim().TrimEnd(',');

Set-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value $File;
```

Here's an explanation of the code:

```
$File = (Get-Content -Path $FilePath) -as [System.Collections.ArrayList];
```

Read the content of the file into an ArrayList instead of the normal Array because it has an Insert method that will be useful later.

```
$Offset = 5;
$InsertStatement = 'INSERT INTO DBname (id1, id2, id3, long, lat, [name]) VALUES';
```

Here we define the number of lines and the INSERT statement.

```
$File.Count..0
```

This returns an array beginning with the count of the number of items and ending with 0.  We'll use this for the indexes of our ArrayList.  It's important to note that we're starting with the high numbers first and descending, because we'll be inserting items into the array which would change the indexes of later items.

```
               | Where-Object {
        ($_ % $Offset) -eq 0
    }
```

Here we filter out any numbers that aren't a multiple of the offset.  `%` is the modulo operator, and returns the integer remainder from dividing the two numbers, so `9 % 5` is `4`, but `10 % 5` is `0`.  It's an easy way to find the indexes we need.

```
     | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -ne 0) {
            $File[$_ - 1] = $File[$_ - 1].Trim().TrimEnd(',');
        }
        $File.Insert($_,$InsertStatement);
    }
```

For each of the indexes that are coming through the pipeline, we have two operations to do.  First, we take the item we need to remove the comma from, trim any trailing whitespace, and then trim the comma from the end.  We skip this if the current index is zero.  Next, we insert the INSERT statement in the index after the item we just removed the comma from.  Note that the indexes here are `$_ - 1` and `$_` because ArrayLists are indexed beginning from zero.  We also don't have to worry about the indexes moving after inserts because we're starting at the end of the file.

```
while (($File[$File.Count - 1] -eq $InsertStatement) -or [System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($File[$File.Count - 1])) {
    $File.Remove($File.Count - 1);
}
```

Remove any line at the end of  the file that is the INSERT statement or is whitespace only.

```
File[$File.Count - 1] = $File[$File.Count - 1].Trim().TrimEnd(',');
```

Remove the last comma from the last line in the file.

```
Set-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value $File;
```

Save the content to `$OutputFile`.

Answer (score 0):

If the input file is very big, all those solutions won't perform well, because they read the whole file into memory. This would be a better solution:

```
$input = 'C:\temp\test.txt'
$output = 'C:\temp\output.txt'
$blocksize = 900

Get-Content $input | foreach {
    if (($_.ReadCount - 1) % $blocksize -eq 0) {
        # the first line of a block
        "INSERT INTO DBname (id1, id2, id3, long, lat, [name]) VALUES"
        $_
    } elseif ($_.ReadCount % $blocksize -eq 0) {
        # the last line of a block
        $_.Replace("),", ")")
        ""
    } else {
        # all other lines
        $_
    }
} | Out-File $output -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Your solution is brilliant!